# How can the java.util.Properties datatype be passed in JSON to the Controller?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

How can I use `java.util.Properties` as a datatype in the bean class? Also, how can I send a `JSON` request object in a rest service?

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestRequest {
        public static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
        public static final int RESET = 0;
        public static final int UPDATE = 1;
        private int msgType = UNDEFINED;
        private Properties properties = new Properties();

        public TestRequest(int msgType) {
            this.setMsgType(msgType);
        }

        public int getMsgType() {
            return msgType;
        }

        public void setMsgType(int msgType) {
            this.msgType = msgType;
        }

        public void setProperty(String itemKey, Object itemValue) {
            this.properties.put(itemKey, itemValue);
        }

        public Object getProperty(String itemKey) {
            return this.properties.get(itemKey);
        }
    }
```

For the bean above, I am sending the following `JSON` data:

```
 {"msgType":7,
      "properties":{"targetItem":{"userName":"vigneshr2311@gmail.com"}}
 }
```

But it's not assigning the value to that bean.
How can I use the `Properties` data type in `JSON`?

Comment: What are you using to convert the `TestRequest` class to `JSON`? How is that mapping performed?

Comment: Try changing the type from `Properties` to `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 0):

`Properties` is essentially a broken class;

Change the type from `Properties` to `Map<String, Object>`; all JSON serialisation libraries can (de)serialize to/from a map.